# JQuery parent and child selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I have googled and searched all over this site, but cant find an answer to my question...
Lets say I have the following selector `$('#me').parents().eq(2).children().eq(1).children().eq(0).children().eq(0);` How would I be able to turn the selected element into a string - "joey" so I could do this: `$(joey);`? All elements are divs and none have class' or id's.

I want to save the string variables into an array, and then join them together so I can add a click function:

```
var divs=['#me','#sister','#brother'];
var divsSel=[];var divs2=[];var ds='';
$(divs).each(function(i,v){
    dS=$(v).parents().eq(2).children().eq(1).children().eq(0).children().eq(0);
    ds=...;\\CODE TO TURN SELECTOR INTO STRING, HERE
    divsSel[i]=ds;
});
divs2=$.merge([],divsSel);
divs2.join();
$(divs2).on('click',function(){...\\It might not be joey..})
```

Comment: If I got you correctly, you just want to have (much) shorter selector?

Comment: That seems a very fragile construction: the slightest change to your html structure and your JS will break. With a class added to the relevant ancestor and the relevant target it could be done with `$('#me').closest('.parentClass').find('joey')`, which is both much easier to read and much more able to cope with html structure changes...

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the jQuery object in a variable. You wont be able to call $(example), but you can just reference it as $example. Consider the following:

```js
// Get the element and store in variable
var $example = $('.me').parent().children().eq(1).children().eq(0);
// Select the output div and write out the text of the stored jQuery obj
$('.output').text("Output = " + $example.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="anotherchild">Example text</div>
    <div class="anotherchild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="me"></div>
</div>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var $joey = $('#me').parents().eq(2).children().eq(1).children().eq(0).children().eq(0);`

and then use like
`$joey.text("blabla");`

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly... Just create variable and save that element(s) in it.

```
var joey = $('#me').parents().eq(2).children().eq(1).children().eq(0).children().eq(0);
```

And then you wouldn't have to use escape character, just "joey;"